# Can I remotely control my Ubuntu PC (16.04) from my BQ m10 Ubuntu Tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, remote, bq, m10

I'm looking for a way to remotely control my desktop on my PC Ubuntu 16.04 from my Ubuntu touch BQ m10. is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. It's called VNC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which level of control are you looking for?
For graphical (VNC) connections you can try Remmina. I have successfully installed Remmina in a new libertine container but haven't tested a lot with that yet. I have only used it to connect to Windows VM's so far.

To install Remmina:

Start by adding a new libertine-container: `libertine-container-manager create --id vivid --type chroot --name 'vivid'` and then install remmina with `libertine-container-manager install-package -i vivid -p remmina`.

Once that is done you'll need a desktop shortcut which is a .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`. 
This file is called `vivid_remmina_0.0.desktop` and contains:
`[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Remmina
Exec=/bin/true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/vivid/rootfs/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/remmina.png
Keywords=Libertine
NotShowIn=Unity;
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
X-Ubuntu-XMir-Enable=true`

Comment: How exaxtly do you install Remmina? 'Cause I want to control one of my laptops from my M10.

Comment: I have updated my answer to incorporate the instructions.