# Security aspects of puritine

Tags: ubuntu-touch, m10, libertine

1. Is puritine container managed only by Canonical team?
   For example, I wasn't be able to add packages in puritine via Terminal app. Or we have a possibility to manage it? (Of course, I think we should have own container to play with Libertine).
2. Is there a directory `/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/puritine/rootfs/home/phablet` for puritine like we have for own container?  Must we have it? Or I deleted it by accident?
3. How to completely reinstall Puritine with all pre-installed apps?

Comment: You can create your own container, see this thread for instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/791025/can-i-remotely-control-my-ubuntu-pc-16-04-from-my-bq-m10-ubuntu-tablet/791059#comment1191733_791059

Comment: I know it, but the question is **only** about **Puritine**, default container

Comment: The answer to (1) is yes, Puritine is managed by Canonical. It is stored in the read-only section of your device's memory and can not be altered.

Comment: Stephen, we have files of Puritine, for example, on ``/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/puritine/rootfs`` and I think we can (in some sense) change or manage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Puritine container is not directly modifiable by end-users. In this sense, it's a special container to maintain a base set of core applications on your device.
2. If you delete puritine's home directory, it *should* recreate the directory structure the next time an application is launched.
3. The puritine click is only available on the pre-built images due to its large size. You can recreate a container with all the same applications pretty easily, but to get the original container back you will either need to manually build/install the click or re-flash the device.

Comment: About 2. Larry, I see, for example, Firefox app (from Puritine) doesn't recreate this directory.

Comment: About 3. Could we possible to extract original Puritine container (or click package) from flash image? I have some experience in that, but I need some info about list of files and directories, if it can help.

Comment: 2. Did you remove the rootfs or the bind-mounted home directory ($HOME/.local/libertine-container/puritine/)? You may need to manually create the base home directory, at which point it might be able to recreate the rest. 3. Maybe the puritine source could help, which can be found on launchpad: https://launchpad.net/puritine

Comment: Larry, I don't know "what I've deleted". I made my experiments with matchbox-keyboard and discovered that I have ``/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/my-container/rootfs/home/phablet``, but have not ``/home/phablet/.cache/libertine-container/puritine/rootfs/home/phablet``

Comment: btw:  ``ls $HOME/.local/libertine-container/puritine
ls: cannot access /home/phablet/.local/libertine-container/puritine: No such file or directory``
``ls $HOME/.cache/libertine-container/puritine
rootfs``

Comment: even more: ``ls /custom/click/com.ubuntu.puritine/current/libertine-data/libertine-container/puritine/rootfs/home`` and see nothing!